# How to access Elasticsearch remotely from Kibana Dashboard?

Tags: elasticsearch, configuration, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

In simple terms, think of trying visualize your data via Kibana from any computer, but once you get to the Kibana dashboard you see 0 hits/results.

I currently have Elasticsearch on a Linux machine with no GUI (simply changing to a GUI is not allowed).

I'm trying to access my indexes using Kibana (Internet Explorer on a Windows machine).

I also have Kibana running on the Linux machine (./kibana), you can't access the Kibana machine via IP/domain unless you start the (./kibana).

But I don't know which ELK files to configure, and what to configure.

Comment: you probably need to look up on kibana.yml config file on your Windows Machine . Follow official guide: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/settings.html

Answer (score 1):

Kibana Dashboards are used to visualize the pre-configred charts, maps, time series etc.

You can not use them to do the administrative operations to your elastic search instance.

Although Kibana does have *Dev Tools* that you can use to query Elastic search and do mappings etc. To list all the indexes, the query to write in *Dev Tools* will be `GET /_cat/indices?v`

However, if you are looking for a GUI based tool to monitor and manage the clusters, nodes etc of Elastic Search, then you can opt for [Monitoring](https://www.elastic.co/products/x-pack/monitoring) that comes with the X-Pack